# objective c singleton shared instance not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am trying to implement a singlton class in my app.
My sharedInstance is as follow

**Appmanager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myAppManager : NSObject{

}
+ (id)sharedManager;
-(void)storeData;
@end
```

**Appmanager.m**

```
#import "myAppManager.h"

@implementation myAppManager
+ (id)sharedManager {
  static myAppManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
     sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {

  }
  return self;
}
-(void)storeData{
    NSLog(@"store data called");
 }
@end
```

Now when i call sharedManager from appdelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as follow

```
[myAppManager sharedManager];
```

It is not calling sharedInstance method, I tried using debugging point but it is not invoking.
what am I doing wrong?

```
[[myAppManager sharedManager] storeData];
```

this is also not calling.

Comment: Your code works for me.  As a tidy up, it should be `MyAppManager` and the sharedManager should return `instanceType` not `id`

Comment: Have you tried creating an instance of myAppManager class explicitly and use it to call storeData method?

Comment: I tried your code brother.It works fine for me.

Comment: but i am putting debug point on sharedManager method, compiler is not reaching there for me. is there any additional setting require like linker flag or anything?

Comment: @ Paulw i tried instanceType instead of id also

Comment: Do you want my tried coding?

Comment: yes i'll try your code

Comment: Check my answer brother.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyAppManager : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedManager;

- (void)storeData;

@end

@implementation MyAppManager

+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    static MyAppManager *singletonObj = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceSecurePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&onceSecurePredicate,^{
                      singletonObj = [[self alloc] init];
                  });

    return singletonObj;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"initialized!");
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)storeData
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

myAppManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myAppManager : NSObject
+ (id)sharedManager;
-(void)storeData;
@end
```

myAppManager.m

```
#import "myAppManager.h"

@implementation myAppManager

+ (id)sharedManager 
{
  static myAppManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init 
{
  if (self = [super init]) {
  }
  return self;
}
-(void)storeData
{
  NSLog(@"store data called");
}
@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myAppManager.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
  myAppManager *appManager;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  appManager = [myAppManager sharedManager];
  [appManager storeData];
  return YES;
}
```

My Console output is

**2016-08-26 17:07:14.805 SingletonClasswithAppDelegate[2383:77763] store data called**